# Removing %20 on output

Tags: javascript, html-encode

I use this code from aweber that passes user information from signup to the next page, 
here is the code from aweber

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var formData = function(){
        var query_string = (location.search)?((location.search.indexOf('#') != -1) ? location.search.substring(1, location.search.indexOf('#')) : location.search.substring(1)) : '';
        var elements = [];
        if(query_string){
            var pairs = query_string.split("&");
            for(i in pairs) { 
                if (typeof pairs[i] == 'string') {
                    var tmp = pairs[i].split("="); 
                    var queryKey = unescape(tmp[0]);
                    queryKey = (queryKey.charAt(0) == 'c') ? queryKey.replace(/\s/g, "_") : queryKey;elements[queryKey] = unescape(tmp[1]);
                }
            }
        }
        return{display: function(key){if(elements[key]){document.write(elements[key]);
    }else {
        document.write("<!--If desired, replace everything between these quotes with a default in case there is no data in the query string.-->");
    }}}}();
</script>
```

then this is the code on the page to display name

`<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("fullname")</script>`

The example output will be `FirstName%20LastName`

Is there a way that `%20` will be removed?

Answer (score 6):

%20 is the symbol for whitespace in url encoding. For some reason your function returns url-encoded data. Try url decoding the output and your %20 should be represented as whitespace.

You can use decodeURI (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp)

EDIT:

Here's a working js-fiddle.

```
var result = 'Firstname%20Lastname';
var result = decodeURI(result);

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = result;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p82HN/

Comment: Hi Stefan,

I really Appreciate your help. I used your code and tried it,

<script type="text/javascript">
var result = formData.display("fullname");
var result = decodeURI(result); document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = result;</script>

<div id="demo"></div>

but it still display %20 on spaces.

Comment: Did you check the jsfiddle out? Anyhow, you don't have to use the document.getElementById and that code, just decode the result and you should be fine. My guess is that you print your result before you decode it. Try this <script type="text/javascript"> decodeURI(formData.display("fullname"))</script>

Comment: Or you probably have to decode it in the display() function, it seems that function doesn't return your String, it prints it directly to your document. Find the code that prints your result to the document and make sure it's decoded before that and you will be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

That data is URL-encoded, so use `decodeURI` or `decodeURIComponent` to decode it:

```
var result = decodeURI(input);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, here is my code
<script type="text/javascript">var named = formData.display("fullname");var result = decodeURI(named);document.write(result);</script>

but it still display %20 and undefined at the end

Comment: Try using unescape(encodeURIComponent((result)); This will utf-8 encode it.

Comment: Hi Stefan, i ried your code is this correct?
<script type="text/javascript">var named = formData.display("fullname");var result = decodeURI(named); var namesd = unescape(encodeURIComponent((result));document.write(namesd);</script>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need urldecode the data,  check out `decodeURIComponent()`